# When did "sale" become "sales event"?

Tags: etymology

It seems like during this generation somebody decided that a "sale" wasn't adequate to describe the selling of discounted goods.  Can anyone shed light on the emergence of the "sales event," which AFAIK is the same thing, only more verbose?

(Or, following the same pattern, should I ask, "Can any one person write an illuminating reponse on...?")

Strangely, if [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sales+event&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csales%20event%3B%2Cc0) is to be trusted, the phrase appeared in the early 1900s and was used as frequently during the second quarter as it is today.

Comment: It's just advertising speak. I doubt there's anything profound to say on the matter, though then again if there is there's no better place to go looking for it than here.

Comment: There are only 20 written instances of [a sales event at](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+sales+event+at%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+sales+event+at%22&tbm=bks&start=10) in Google Books (compared to over 2 million of [a sale at](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+sale+at%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)). What kind of answer do you expect for such a rare but otherwise unremarkable usage?

Comment: It's marketing speak, which tries to make something mundane sound more exciting than it really is. I don't think I've ever heard the phrase outside of an advertisement for said event.

Comment: Google Ngrams finds in the neighborhood of 500 matches for "sales event" in its Google Books database, the vast majority of them in texts published since 1947. By the way, anytime you want to see whether reported matches in Ngrams are "to be trusted," just click the relevant date-range link beneath "Search in Google Books" below the Ngrams graph, and you can quickly see a series of links to (many of) the examples that the graph is based on.

Answer (score 2):

The first instances of "sales event" recorded in the Google Books library/database happened more than 100 years ago. From “[How Retailers Use the News Letter](http://books.google.com/books?id=11ZBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A6soVJaRCIGkigLKooDwDQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBjg8#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20event%22&f=false),” in *Business Correspondence*, volume 1 (1911):

> Then there are the letters that tell of the purchase of goods. A retailer puts new value into his letter when he writes that he has purchased the entire stock of the bankrupt Brown & Brown at thirty-eight cents on the dollar and that the goods are to be placed on sale the following Monday morning at prices that will make it a rare **sales event**.
>
> Package enclosures, statement enclosures, and striking announcements on the hoods of all the delivery cars contributed their share of the publicity of this big sales event.

From a [Parker Pen ad](http://books.google.com/books?id=tHlNAAAAYAAJ&q=%22sales+event%22&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A6soVJaRCIGkigLKooDwDQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwATg8) in *Collier’s*, volume 51, part 2 (1913) [snippet view]:

> **15,000 Dealers will participate in this Big Sales Event—September 1st to 6th**
>
> I am making a special opportunity for you to buy a fountain pen to advantage. During Jack Knife Safety Week — September 1st to 6th fifteen thousand progressive Dealers will be prepared to meet the tremendous demand for Parker Pens.
>
> Our advance orders for this **sales event** have been enormous. Thousands of pens have been shipped to make Dealers’ assortments complete and your opportunity for selection ample.

The preceding ad was directed at dealers, of course, but you can see the complementary ad touting this “big sales event” to retail customers in [*The Literary Digest*](http://books.google.com/books?id=rQw8AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA336&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QrIoVP7bKqXNiwKb04GoCw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAzhG#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20event%22&f=false) (August 30, 1913).

From “[Make September Big in the Notion Department](http://books.google.com/books?id=KYBBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA309&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eKkoVLGwH4arogTDmIHoBA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20event%22&f=false),” in *Dry Goods Economist* (1914):

> Any merchandising or **sales event** that adds new customers to the store's established clientele builds business. It is plain that an event that stimulates sales is likely to build some business. And vice versa.
>
> Any merchandising or advertising event in the store that in stimulating sales or building business puts the store favorably in customers’ minds creates prestige. That is, it originates collective good-ill, the most valuable of all the tangible assets in business.

From “[Housekeepers’ Week Sale](http://books.google.com/books?id=0ps7AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA5-PA72&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oKkoVI-eH9PqoATfnoDABA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20event%22&f=false),” in *Dry Goods Reporter* (September 18, 1915):

> Half sheet announcement cards were conspicuously displayed in the windows of the various stores and throughout the establishment. All these were announcing the coming and the arrival of “Housekeeper’s Week.”
>
> Package enclosures, statement enclosures, and striking announcements on the hoods of all the delivery cars contributed their share of the publicity of this big **sales event**.

From “[Advertising Field Notes](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dh07AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA682&dq=%22sales+event%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y6koVNTFJYLloASxqYKoBA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwATgy#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20event%22&f=false),” in *The Editor & Publisher and The Journalist* (November 27, 1915):

> A big weekly **sales event** has been inaugurated by the retail merchants in Louisville, Kentucky, known as “Suburban Day.” The plan is to set aside Thursday of each week as a time to advertise by special bargains to suburbanites, to give free amusements and to award cash and merchandise prizes to those who join a Suburban Club.

The breathless excitement with which these big sales events are announced could have been ripped out of the headlines of today's advertising supplements.

On a tangentially related note, the phrase "super sale" goes back almost as far (to [May 1921](http://books.google.com/books?id=rOs-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA165&dq=%22super+sale%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p8coVNPBDurJigKnvoHIBw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwATg8#v=onepage&q=%22super%20sale%22&f=false)), although "one-day super-sale" appears to date back only to [1927](http://books.google.com/books?id=u9ZAAAAAIAAJ&q=%22super+sale%22&dq=%22super+sale%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QcMoVJPvMMKCiwLluIC4Ag&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCDgK). The relative newcomer is "sales extravaganza" which debuted in [1970](http://books.google.com/books?id=WzEcAQAAMAAJ&q=%22sales+extravaganza%22&dq=%22sales+extravaganza%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q8soVNvgJae5igKN9ICYCw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCTgK), by Google Books' reckoning.

---

**Update (3/30/2016)**

A search of the Library of Congress's Chronicling America database of old newspapers finds numerous examples of "sales event" from 1910 and earlier. For example, from an advertisement for [Ramsay Bros. Dry Goods Co.](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86063952/1906-07-09/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1836&index=3&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+sales&proxdistance=5&date2=1910&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in the *Guthrie [Oklahoma] Daily Leader* (July 9, 1906):

> Let us tell you the whys and wherefores. Let us give you some plain, open-faced reasons why the July Clearance is the greatest **sales event** of the year.

From an ad for [Bee Hive](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86091110/1905-07-14/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1836&index=1&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Event+Sales&proxdistance=5&date2=1906&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *Lewiston [Idaho] Inter-state News* (July 14, 1905):

> > We will refund railroad fare during this SALE—you are out nothing but your time in coming and going—While here we will make your time worth the trip by giving you immense reductions in every department IN THE HOUSE. All trains lead you to the Greatest **Sales Event** ever held in Lewiston.

From an ad for [Goldenberg's, "The Dependable Store"](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1904-12-01/ed-1/seq-11/#date1=1836&index=11&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+sales&proxdistance=5&date2=1906&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *[Washington, D.C.] Evening Star* (December 1, 1904):

> There's a double incentive for bargain making now—because holiday goods are crowding us for room, and we must be rid of everything that bears the slightest relation to "remnants." Many complete lines fall under the clearance ban, too—and, altogether, tomorrow may be one of the most important **sales events** of the season.

From an ad for [Cohn's Dry Goods Store](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85058130/1903-06-28/ed-1/seq-24/#date1=1836&index=3&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Event+Sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1903&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *Salt Lake [City, Utah] Herald* (June 28, 1903):

> The Best Assorted Stock in Salt Lake to be Closed Out Without Reserve at Cost and Far Below Cost, Regardless of Value, Making a **Sale Event** Embodying the FIERCEST AND SWIFTEST PRICE CUTTING EVER KNOWN

From an ad for [Red Boot Shoe Co.](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025294/1902-12-08/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1836&index=2&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1903&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *Butte [Montana] Inter Mountain* (December 8, 1902):

> To be powerless to name none but the lowest price quotations ever utilized! Circumstances, the reincorporation and other kindred things of vital importance stamp this sale as GRANDER and BIGGER than the WIDEST **sale event** ever deserving intelligent thought and study.

And from an ad for [Connolly and Wallace, "Scranton's Shopping Center"](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026355/1901-03-27/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1836&index=4&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Event+Sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1), in the *Scranton [Pennsylvania] Tribune* (March 27, 1901):

> Connolly & Wallace's Collar Sale. An Extraordinary **Sale Event** in Collars and Cuffs

As the last three examples suggest, the wording sale event seems to be more common than the wording "sales event" in the earliest years. "Sales events" makes three of its earliest appearances in advertisements in 1899 (in [Sacramento, California](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015104/1899-10-16/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1836&index=15&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=EVENTS+SALES&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), in 1895 (in [Washington, D.C.](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1895-01-23/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1836&index=10&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=events+sales&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), and in 1892 (again in [Sacramento, California](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015104/1892-01-28/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1836&index=8&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=sales-events&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), whereas instances of "sale event" appear 1900 (in [Seattle, Washington](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045604/1900-01-07/ed-1/seq-21/#date1=1836&index=10&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Event+Sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) and [Richmond, Virginia](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038614/1900-10-16/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1836&index=19&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=events+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), in 1899 (in [Sacramento, California](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82015104/1899-07-13/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1836&index=17&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=events+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) and [Rock Island, Illinois](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn92053934/1899-08-11/ed-1/seq-2/#date1=1836&sort=relevance&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=1&words=events+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2)), in 1898 (in [Los Angeles, California](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85042461/1898-02-27/ed-1/seq-15/#date1=1836&index=13&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=events+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), in 1897 (in [Hopkinsville Kentucky](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86069395/1897-06-11/ed-1/seq-5/#date1=1836&index=5&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), in 1896 (in [Topeka, Kansas](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82016014/1896-11-26/ed-1/seq-5/#date1=1836&index=19&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+Sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) and [Westminster, Maryland](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038292/1896-01-11/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1836&index=18&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Events+Sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)), and in 1894 [in Jamestown, Dakota Territory](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85042405/1894-10-25/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1836&index=8&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=EVENT+SALE&proxdistance=5&date2=1901&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)).

The earliest of all such instances may be this ad for [C.H. Gilman](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn82014381/1890-08-11/ed-1/seq-1/#date1=1836&index=13&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=event+sale&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in the *Sacramento [California] Daily Record-Union* (August 11, 1890):

> We can look back on the past few weeks as the greatest triumph in the history of clearance sales. In arranging for the next few weeks, when this memorable **sale event** will be at an end, and goods resume their regular prices, we have determined to offer even better inducements than at the commencement.

However, advertisements claiming that a sale was "the event of the season" go back farther still—at least to this ad for [Menken's](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045160/1884-11-21/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1836&sort=relevance&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=0&words=EVENT+SALE&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=2) in the *Memphis [Tennessee] Daily Appeal* (November 21, 1884):

> COLOSSAL CARPET **SALE** at MENKEN'S THE **EVENT** OF THE SEASON!

It's easy to see how such wording led to closer association of *sales* with *events* in ads like this one for [Heyman & Company](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn98066392/1891-01-26/ed-1/seq-8/#date1=1836&index=3&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Events+Sales&proxdistance=5&date2=1896&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=sales+event&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) from the *[Grand Rapids, Michigan] Telegram-Herald* (January 26, 1891):

> Our Faith Kept With You in the Past Shall be Our Guarantee to Do Just As We Advertise in the Future. We Intend to Make These Annual Clearance **Sales' Events** Long to Be Remembered.